# Flash CC - AS3 disable "continue" buttons in a 2nd version of an .swf application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a .swf application with multiple scenes. It is a yes/no decision-based application that walks an employee through an SOP. In some situations the employee is instructed to transfer a caller to another department.

I have created a second version of the application that allows the next department to "continue" (ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_xxx) to the next steps.

Is there an easy way to be able to activate/deactivate the "continue" buttons from one location? There are hundreds of these buttons. I do not want to have to run duplicate updates / fixes on 2 different files. I would like have one full version that includes all button functionality, and then be able to save a copy after deactivating all "continue" buttons.

Comment: Probably, but without seeing your code no one can really help you.

Comment: I disagree with you, LDMS. I am not asking anyone to edit code for me. I am asking what methods / best practices are available in AS3 that would allow you to create many instances of a button, give them all a function (in this case ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_xxx functions) and then deactivate all instances of this button throughout the entire document.

Comment: Could I do this globally with a boolean? I am learning AS3, but I have a very, very long way to go.

Comment: Stack overflow is for specific questions - this one is too broad in it's current state.  Search the web for how to instantiate an object from flash library.  For loops (repeating similar functionality) etc.

Comment: If I could formulate a more specific question I most likely would not feel the need to ask it. Unfortunately, "You don't know what you don't know" applies to me right now. If my question is "too broad" for someone of your stature to answer, don't bother. I was hoping for someone to take a little bit of time to help guide me in the right direction rather then trying to assert blogging dominance over an aspiring AS3 learner. You disappoint me.

Comment: It's not a matter of stature or dominance, it's a matter of following the guidelines of this site. StackOverflow is not for broad questions - read the guidelines before asking more questions.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: From the provided link:"if your question generally covers…

-a specific programming problem, or
-a software algorithm, or
-software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
-a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: Your smug comments & down vote are not appreciated. To sum up my question: can I use a Boolean value to disable all instances of a button throughout all scenes in an AS3 document? And, if not does anyone have another suggestion for me?

Comment: No one is being smug.  You don't seem to understand that there is no concise way to answer your question.  Someone would have answered already if there was.  At least your last comment (aside from rude accusations) got a little more specific.  In the future I will just avoid telling you why your question will sit unanswered forever since you apparently do not receive feedback well.

Comment: I would appreciate that very much. As a new user I tend to follow a few very basic rules. One of which is that I do not  take advise on how to use this website from someone who cannot correctly represent the name of the website. It is two words, both of which should be capitalized as it is a proper name.

Answer (score -1):

While I am sure that this is a poor solution to my question: I decided to duplicate the "continue" buttons in my document. I grayed out the duplicates (or blocker buttons) & copied them on top of the active buttons. I will then make any revisions to my project and save a second copy after removing the blocker button from the library.